# Having trouble with rsync version on mac when using it with lsyncd

Tags: macos, lua, rsync, ubuntu-server, lsyncd

I am trying to synchronize a folder on my mac with one on an ubuntu server 16.06 system that I built. The problem is with the rsync version. Here is what I did. I created a file in /var/log/lsyncd/ and called it lsyncd.conf.lua. The following are its contents:

```
settings {
 logfile = "/var/log/lysncd/lsyncd.log", -- Sets the log file
 statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd-status.log" -- Sets the status log file
 }
sync {
 default.rsyncssh, -- uses the rsyncssh defaults Take a look here: https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/blob/master/default-rsyncssh.lua
 delete = false, -- Doesn't delete files on the remote host eventho they're deleted at the source. This might be beneficial for some not for others
 source="/Users/alixchristakaze/Desktop", -- Your source directory to watch
 host="", -- The remote host (use hostname or IP)
 targetdir="", -- the target dir on remote host, keep in mind this is absolute path
 rsync = {
 binary = "/usr/local/bin/rsync",
 archive = true, -- use the archive flag in rsync
 perms = true, -- Keep the permissions
 owner = true, -- Keep the owner
 _extra = {"-a"}, -- Sometimes permissions and owners isn't copied correctly so the _extra can be used for any flag in rsync
 },
 maxProcesses = 1 -- We only want to use a maximum of 1 rsync processes at same time
 }
```

I get this error when I run this command: `lsyncd /var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua`

```
Warn: Using /dev/fsevents which is considered an OSX internal interface.

Warn: Functionality might break across OSX versions (This is for 10.5.X)
Warn: A hanging Lsyncd might cause Spotlight/Timemachine doing extra work.
Error: Cannot access /dev/fsevents monitor! (1:Operation not permitted)
```

As you can see I added this line `binary = "/usr/local/bin/rsync",` hoping it would tell system to use the rsync I installed through homebrew. However, I am getting the error above.
I have the latest mac version 10.12.3 and my rsync version is 3.1.2 . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just read this "currently I don't advice using Lsyncd on OSX, sorry, the interface is old and has bugs with exchange events" back in Jun 8, 2016 from this link [https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/issues/384]. I don't know if a solution has been found yet or someone knowledgeable in Lua can write a patch for it. The project is on Github (https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd).

Comment: `Error: Cannot access /dev/fsevents monitor! (1:Operation not permitted)`, you just needed to run the command with `sudo` in front of it ;)